# Will Ubuntu boot if I install on a hard drive that isn't the Windows boot disk via WUBI?

Tags: wubi

I been thinking about to install ubuntu again which wubi.

If i install it on my E drive and not the C drive(Windows), will it still dual-booting and work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the installation size option, but to answer your first question, if you install it on the E drive instead of the C drive it should dual boot with no problems.

Comment: I mean the "slower" the ubuntu itself, not the install.

Comment: I don’t believe that it would slow anything down. I could be wrong, but I have used wubi and I do not recall it being much slower than when I installed it by USB.